# Matlab Auido Signal Formant Frequincies

Tags: matlab, audio, signals, frequency

I can draw the formant frequency graph in MATLAB but I can't get the peaks on the graph as output numerically. Does anyone know how to do that?

Here is my code:

```
clc;
clearvars;
close all;
%% Reading Audio file 
[xa, fs] = audioread('a_hw.wav');
hw = spectrum.welch;
xapsdw = psd(hw, xa, 'fs', fs );
x1 = xapsdw(1:2200);
plot(x1)
figure, plot(xapsdw);

NFFT = 44100;
[Pxxa,Fxa] = pwelch(xa,length(xa),0,NFFT,fs);
% figure, plot(Fxa, Pxxa);

hold on;
[~,Ia] = max(Pxxa);
ffreqa = abs(Fxa(Ia));
fprintf('Formant Frequency', ffreqa);
plot(Fxa(Ia), Pxxa(Ia), 'o');
title('Welch Periodogram of Signal "a"');
xlabel('Frequency(Hz)');
ylabel('Power/Frequency');
```

Comment: If I’m reading this correctly, I think this is really just a question on using fprintf https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html , which takes c-like formatting operators e.g `fprintf('Formant Frequency %f', ffreqa);`

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work.

Comment: What did not work when you tried the advice from fdcpp? Did it output anything? Produce an error?

Comment: Index exceeds the number of arrayt elements (1) .
Error in example2 ( line 8 )
x1 = xapsdw (1:2200);

It produced this error.

Comment: I think this is quite a few problems wrapped up in one, which is never a great thing as you want to only be dealing with one problem at a time. The question(s) you are asking are not fundamentally bad questions, sadly they _are_ bad Stack Overflow questions. What I would recommend is actually speak to and engage with the staff in your institute for advice or assistance. They should be able to help demonstrate how you approach errors in programming and how to go about solving them.

Comment: For instance, can you execute each line one at a time? When you get an error on a line, start there. It doesn't necessarily matter what comes after the troublesome line. So, if you have a program that is 100 lines long, but it fails on `line 8`, you actually only have a program 8 lines long. In this case `x1 = xapsdw(1:2200);` is the error line, so scrutinise it a little. What size is `xapsdw`? (i.e. `size(xapsdw)`)